# Filtering Data by specific week of Current_Time | Postgre SQL WHERE

Tags: postgresql, time, where-clause

Trying to make a query that will extract data for the specific week of when the data is pulled. Tried messing with NOW() and Between but its not completely accurate to getting a specific week of data.

Example: Week 02    Jan. 9, 2023    Jan. 15, 2023

- if query is ran Jan 13th, the query would know to search from Jan 9th to Jan 15th 2023

  SQL:

> ```
>  SELECT * 
>     WHERE started_job_date between now()::date - 7 and now()::date
> ```

Comment: Try `date_trunc('week', now())`

Comment: Would there be a method that does not have to be in the SELECT statement?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Does the following work?  `select * from your_table where started_job_date <@ daterange(date_trunc('week', current_date)::date, (date_trunc('week', current_date) + interval '1 week')::date)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no native process for determining the week in which a given date falls. The query from @MikeOrganek
should be sufficient if you can use `current_date`, if however you wish to provide an arbitrary date you can create a function which returns a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) which contains the ISO week in which that date falls.

```
create or replace function week_of( date_in date )
  returns daterange
 language sql
as $$
    select daterange( date_trunc('week', date_in)::date
                    , ((date_trunc('week', date_in)) + interval '7 day')::date
                    , '[)'
                    );
$$;
```

Then use that function in your query with the [range contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) (**<@**) as in below (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OXfbmlKg))

```
select *
  from jobs 
 where start_dt <@ week_of('2023-01-13'::date) 
 order by start_dt, name;
```

I am not exactly sure what you are getting at by *Would there be a method that does not have to be in the SELECT statement?* Virtually everything in an RDBMS stems from a Select statement (except perhaps the `returning` clause on DML statements). I guess you could write the above function as:

```
create or replace function week_of_wo_select( date_in date )
  returns daterange
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin
   return daterange( date_trunc('week', date_in)::date
                    , ((date_trunc('week', date_in)) + interval '7 day')::date
                    , '[)'
                    );
end; 
$$;
```

And avoid writing `Select ...`, however that involves **way more overhead**, and thus much slower.